# WebRTC connection - STUN and TURN at the same time?

Tags: google-chrome, connection, webrtc, stun, turn

2 different computers, 2 Chromes, 2 different networks.

I am making a WebRTC call between 2 peers described above and using **getStats()** to check the connection. The thing is that in one Chrome it shows "**turn**" in "connection" property and on another it shows "**stun**".

Is that possible? I thought you either connected through one or another?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible.

The first browser will use the ICE Candidate retrieved by its TURN server.
The second browser will use the ICE Candidate retrieved by STUN (eg. Public IP address).

In fact, TURN servers don't have to relay WebRTC flows to a remote TURN server. If the peer is able to contact the distant TURN server without using its TURN then only one relay server will be used for the communication.

However, you can use the following option `"iceTransports": "relay"` in the configuration of your `RTCPeerConnection` of your webapp to force both browser to use a TURN server.

Comment: So that means there is still a relay between peers, isn't it? It is like PEER1<STUN>TURNSERVER<TURN>PEER2 ?

Comment: Yes you're right :)
In this case, Peer 1 will use its STUN ICE Candidate to join Peer 2 TURN ICE Candidate.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Relay candidate selected in both end is rare scenario, for the relay cases most of the time you will end up with relay candidate in one end and server-reflexive/peer-reflexive candidate in other end, though the server-reflexive/peer-reflexive candidate selected end is identifying itself as STUN or peer-to-peer candidate but its actually relay connection, best thing is to detect your original connection type is to check the candidate type of your both end.